# How to properly download a video using React so as not to get a 206 status

Tags: video, html5-video

I am trying to dynamically load a video in to a React component like so:

```
<video
  ref={handleRef}
  key={deviceImageData.name} id="my-video" muted autoPlay loop>
  <source src={path} type='video/mp4'/>
  <p className="vjs-no-js">
    To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
    <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
  </p>
</video>
```

However, if I load on desktop it is fine, but on mobile (or sometimes on ipad), I get a 206 status, which leads me to believe that the video is being PARTIALLY downloaded.

Do I need to create a function for continuing to make http requests until the full file is downloaded and use `<souce src={fullVideo}` instead of trying to just pull the whole video like so: `<source src={path}`?

Or maybe I need to completely change the encoding of the video so that it doesn't allow streaming, so that the whole video is downloaded before an attempt is made to play it?

Thanks

Comment: `I get a 206 error` Are you talking about HTTP status code 206? Thats not an error.

Comment: ok sure, error or not, it leads to un-desirable behaviour: ie the video not fully loading/playing. Question amended

Comment: a 206 means the browser will just ask for more video when it reaches the end of the bit downloaded. are you not getting the entire video to play?  (that is not stated in your question)

Comment: The browser decides 206 vs 200. I don't think you can control that.  If you set he video to autoplay, it will begin playing as soon as the browser "thinks" it has enough of the video buffered to finish the playback.  even if you could force it to wait - that would just delay the video playback.  In your devTools, do you see a 2nd request for the rest of the video?  Does the entire video not play?